# mongoimport csv and split the data string into two columns

Tags: mongodb, sha, mongoimport

I am quite new to MongoDB and I am working on mongoimport to import CSV data into the DB. My CSV data looks like this:

[image: excel data example]

and I would like the data in the MongoDB collection as,

```
{ "_id" : BinData(0,"5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8"), "c" : 3303003 }
{ "_id" : BinData(0,"3D4F2BF07DC1BE38B20CD6E46949A1071F9D0E3D"), "c" : 2900049 }
{ "_id" : BinData(0,"7C222FB2927D828AF22F592134E8932480637C0D"), "c" : 2680521 }
{ "_id" : BinData(0,"6367C48DD193D56EA7B0BAAD25B19455E529F5EE"), "c" : 2670319 }
{ "_id" : BinData(0,"E38AD214943DAAD1D64C102FAEC29DE4AFE9DA3D"), "c" : 2310111 }
```

I have tried the below command but it is importing not correctly and keeps the data in one column only.

```
mongoimport --fields "_id.binary(base64),c.int32()" --db mgdb --collection sample --type csv --file C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\pwned-passwords-sha1-ordered-by-count-v7\\pwned-passwords-sha1-ordered-by-count-v7.csv
```

It would be a great help if someone can steer me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you advise what the relation is to C#?

Comment: Have you tried the option `columnsHaveTypes` as you are specifying the field and column type.

Comment: @prasad_ I have tried the columnHaveTypes but it inserts the record as {"_id": "5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8: 3303003"}.  This is the command I tried mongoimport --fields "_id.string(),c.string()" --columnsHaveTypes  --db local_pwned --collection new_test --type csv --file C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\pwned-passwords-sha1-ordered-by-count-v7\\pwned-passwords-sha1-ordered-by-count-v7.csv

Comment: @Llama the relation with C# is that I am connecting my C# application with MongoDB :)

Comment: No, not "what is the relation to your application?" What is the relation to your question? There isn't any C# code here.

Comment: Does it behave the same if you use a comma to separate the values instead of a colon?

Comment: Hi, @Joe Thanks for your reply. The problem is I cannot change the CSV file because it is a 12GB file containing these types of strings. So, it is a lot of work to change the: to a comma.

Comment: @Joe I tried with a smaller set of data. The query I have mentioned above doesn't recognize the column value property. The error says "_id" could not parse the token '01B307ACBA4F54F55AAFC33BB06BBBF6CA803E9A,2293209' to type binary

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your CSV file correctly before passing it into mongoimport. mongoimport just tries to import what you give it so you need to make sure what you're giving it is in the correct format.

It looks like what you currently have is in this format:

```
_id
5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8:3303003
3D4F2BF07DC1BE38B20CD6E46949A1071F9D0E3D:2900049
```

But you need it in this format:

```
_id,c
5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8,3303003
3D4F2BF07DC1BE38B20CD6E46949A1071F9D0E3D,2900049
```

To do transformations like this on a CSV it's easier to use a text editor like VSCode and do a search and replace. A CSV is just a text file after all. Note that doing a search and replace in Excel might not work since it will replace the `:` inside the field, instead of separating it into a new field like to want. Excel can try to be too clever sometimes.

You could also use a command line tool like sed by downloading [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/):

```
sed "s/:/,/g" file.csv > new_file.csv
```

But unless you're already familiar with sed, a text editor might be easiest.